# in Bash Script, how to read a file and split all lines into a two-dimensional array

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Content of the file:

```
Class_one 23
Class_two 17
Class-three 22
..
```

How to read the file and split all lines into a two-dimensional array? like java. Like:

```
arr[0][0] = Class_one    arr[0][1] = 23
arr[1][0] = Class_two    arr[1][1] = 17
```

thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Comment: The problem is that I have no idea~

Comment: How about picking a language you know? Or picking up a tutorial book or web site?

Comment: Do you maintain any other programming language? Use that! Arrays are not so well supported in bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU bash has no two-dimensional array. A workaround is an associative array.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A arr  # declare an associative array
declare -i c=0

# read from stdin (from file)
while read -r label number; do
  arr[$c,0]="$label"; arr[$c,1]="$number"
  c=c+1
done < file

# print array arr
for ((i=0;i<${#arr[@]}/2;i++)); do
  echo "${arr[$i,0]} ${arr[$i,1]}"
done
```

---

See: `help declare` and `man bash`

Comment: Yes, take a look at output of: `help read`. `label` and `number` are variables.

Answer (score 0):

@Cyrus's approach involves associative arrays which is noticeably only in bash 4.0 and up. Below is what works for bash sub-4.0. Note that nowadays Mac's are still shipped w/ bash 3.x.

```
#!/bin/bash
l=0; while read -a a$l; do
    let l++;
done < ${data_file_name}

## now everything is stored in the 2D array ${a};
## $(($l+1)) is #rows, and ${#a0[@]} is #cols;
## elements can be accessed in the form of "ai[j]";
## e.g., a0[0] is the element at (0,0);
## but to access "ai[j]" using var ${i} and ${j}
## as indexes can be a just little tricky

echo "#rows: $((l+1))"
echo "#cols: ${#a0[@]}"$'\n'
echo "element at (0, 0): ${a0[0]}"

## the following shows how to access an element at (i,j)
i=1; j=1
tmp_a="a${i}[${j}]"; echo "element at ($i, $j): ${!tmp_a}"$'\n'

## the following shows how to iterate through the 2D array
echo "all elements printed from top left to bottom right:"
for i in `eval echo {0..$l}`; do
    for j in `eval echo {0.."$((${#a0[@]}-1))"}`; do
        tmp_a="a${i}[${j}]"; echo ${!tmp_a}
    done
done
```